# Eclipse-CDT index file that is included via gcc -include

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to work on an existing project that I have opened in Eclipse. However, nearly all the files show errors of `Symbol 'SOME_SYMBOL' could not be resolved.` The reason for that is that a header file is included via the gcc "-include" option. How can I get the Eclipse CDT indexer to index this file.

The compile command looks like this

```
gcc -include config.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse does support indexing individual files, it just doesn't display the tab by default:

1. Go to: Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Property Pages Settings
2. Check: 'Display "Include Files" tab'
3. Press Apply
4. Go to: Project > Properties > Paths and Symbols > Include Files
5. Add your files to be include for GNU C and GNU C++

Answer (score 0):

It may not have the correct location of the .h file. Eclipse is looking for config.h in your workspace directory. You can either point eclipse directly to the file by using #include "filepath\config.h"

Or

You can navigate to project properties -> C/C++ Build -> settings -> includes 
here you can add the folder where config.h is located in the -i options.

Now you should be able to add #include "config.h" to your cpp file.

Comment: This is not the solution I am looking for. I cannot add #include "config.h" to the existing files.